# Error with docker-php-ext-install command

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I get this error when trying to build a container ( in Laravel 7 project):

```
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring pdo_mysql]: exit code: 1
```

This is Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin 
--filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN sudo composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8000
```

This is docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  frontend:
    image: antoniopapa1991/admin-frontend
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app

  backend:
    container_name: admin_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_DATABASE: admin
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 8000:8000 
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app

  db:
    container_name: admin_db
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
```

I tried different PHP images but the result is the same. Not sure where to look. The code seems to be working in tutorial I follow but not on my host. Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636

Is there some error or there is another problem?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was psr dependency issue.
After using php 8 image, Dockerfile was built without further issues.